# Module not found error while importing some icons from Material-UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I got Module not found: Can't resolve '@material-ui/icons/... error while importing some icons like `VolunteerActivism`, `AdminPanelSettings`. Why it occurs for some icons? Please help me to sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're the new icons that are only available in **MUI v5**. See the list of icons in [v4](https://v4.mui.com/components/material-icons/) and [v5](https://mui.com/components/material-icons/#main-content). To use them, you need to update to version 5.